# Mount multiple NFS-Servers

Tags: nfs, mount, ubuntu-16.04, automount, autofs

I have multiple nfs-servers running in my network.

What is the best way to mount all servers on my ubuntu?

While researching I came across multiple possible solutions: `autofs`, `fstab`, `automount`. Any best practices worth sharing?

Comment: Technically in NFS you mount _exports_, not _servers_. Is your question about ways to discover available NFS exports?

Comment: yes, you got it right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no best way. You should use whatever automounter or mounting table or script that works best for you, which would requiring learning about what you want to do and then picking the best option based on your own requirements.

In most cases, learning about the `/etc/fstab` file and how that works is a good place to start.